# Scroll detect on 0 position

Tags: java, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
  $(window).bind('wheel mousewheel', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.deltaY >= 0) {
        console.log('Scroll down');
        $('body').addClass('smart-menu');
    }

    else {
        console.log('Scroll up');
        $('body').removeClass('smart-menu');
        $('body').addClass('pin-menu');

    }
});
```

The problem appears when I am at the top of the page and I will use the scroll up again and then add the `pin-menu` class. when I am at the very top of the page I want the `pin-menu` no longer to be shown when scrolling up
 Does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Comment: `if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0)` .. then at the top

Comment: Working good. Thanks man.